# Create new rows conditionally

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with ID, year, and value (with 0 or 1). I want to create a few rows to fill with 2 years before the existing year and 3 years after the existing year for each ID. For the 2 extra years before the existing year, the value is the same wit the existing value. For the years after the existing year, the value is the opposite of the existing value. For example, for the dataframe below:

```
ID  year    value
A   2005    1
B   2006    0
C   2007    1
```

I want to a new dataframe like below:

```
ID  year    value
A   2003    1
A   2004    1
A   2005    1
A   2006    0
A   2007    0
A   2008    0
B   2004    0
B   2005    0
B   2006    0
B   2007    1
B   2008    1
B   2009    1
C   2005    1
C   2006    1
C   2007    1
C   2008    0
C   2009    0
C   2010    0
```

Below is what I tried. I am not sure I am on the right direction.

```
df['year1'] = np.where(df['value'] = 1, 0,1)
df['year2'] = np.where(df['value'] = 1, 0,1)
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars= 'ID', var_name = 'year')
```

Comment: You have mismatched brackets in the first two lines.

Comment: Thank you for point out. Despite correcting them, I feel I am still in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try `map` function?

```
df['year_before'] = df['year'].map(lambda x: str(int(x) - 2))
df['value_before'] = df['value']
df['year_after'] = df['year'].map(lambda x: str(int(x) + 3))
df['value_after'] = df['value'].map(lambda x: 1 - x)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems your code creates new columns rather than rows.

Comment: Used your method coupled with a few pd.melt/pd.concat and get it done. Thanks.